# darktable-cli fails because of locked database file

Tags: darktable, automation

I'm using `darktable-cli` to export photos from my library. I started to get an error with the latest version(2.6.1). It's a segmentation fault with error

```
[init] the database lock file contains a pid that seems to be alive in your system: 16768
[init] database is locked, probably another process is already using it
```

I'm always getting this error if darktable is running. And if darktable is not running, most of the times. I have a script running 4 instances `darktable-cli` in parallel. As I mentioned I didn't have this error with the previous versions.

I don't know how darktable works internally, but I feel like there shouldn't be a need for library for the cli. Is there a need for it?

As a workaroung I tried changing the library for the darktable calls. But `--library` option is ignored. Darktable still worked with the default library. The command is:

`darktable-cli raw-file xmp-file jpg-file --width 1920 --height 1080 --core --conf plugins/imageio/format/jpeg/quality=50 --conf plugins/imageio/storage/disk/overwrite=true --library /tmp/darktable.db`

Is this command argument correct?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using Darktable myself, so I can't check it myself but this might be a re-occurrence of a [bug that has been fixed](https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/11314) two years ago. You might file a bug-report with them and while it's been discussed/fixed, you can revert back to the previous version to keep your stuff functional.

Edit: Checking the [documentation](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/overview_chapter.html#darktable_commandline_parameters) you might try to call darktable-cli explicitly setting the library to `:memory:`, so that it looks something like this:

```
darktable-cli [...] --library ':memory:'
```

Comment: `--conf --library ':memory:'` didn't work neither

Comment: @rosencreuz Shouldn't that be `--core --library ':memory:'`? What's the error message?

Comment: `--core --library ':memory:'`  also doesn't work. Same error. Very long error message starting with `[init] the database lock file contains a pid that seems to be alive in your system: 1915
[init] database is locked, probably another process is already using it` and last line is `segmentation fault (core dumped)  darktable-cli  test.jpg --width 1920 --height 1080 --core`.

Answer (score 3):

```
darktable-cli $src $xmp $export [options] --core --library ':memory:' --configdir '/dev/shm/$uniquevalue'
```

It seems that there's also a `data.db` in the --configdir parameter (default: `$HOME/.config/darktable`) which also gets locked by a darktable session.  This probably holds user preferences and styles, but if an xmp sidecar is specified then it's not important.  (One could probably copy the data.db into a unique instance if necessary.)

Here's a snippet using GNU parallel:

```
parallel "darktable-cli {} somesettings.xmp export/{/} [opts] --core --library ':memory:' --configdir '/dev/shm/{/.}/' ; rm -rf /dev/shm/{/.}" ::: *.jpg
```

Darktable will create a new data.db in a dir with the source filename exclusively for that darktable-cli session and remove it after exporting.

Notes for this example:

- My source images are jpgs.  Change the `*.jpg` to a glob matching your sources (or pipe it to parallel).
- `{/.}` strips out dirpath and extensions from files, so that can be used to specify output file type
- I'm creating the temporary configdir in memory (/dev/shm) for speed; each instance is ~152KB
- `--configdir ':memory:'` creates a literal `:memory:` directory, so doesn't have the same magic as `--library` :)

Hope this helps, I feel like this is just a workaround and that darktable-cli should probably not lock or open the data.db as read-only.

Comment: Some questions: (1) what does {/} without the . do? (2) what does the ::: do?

Comment: `{/}` Basename of input line. `::: arguments` Use arguments from the command line instead of stdin (standard input). And I want to thank you @anomalyconcept for the elegant workaround, I have a script to parallel process raw files from sd card (copy, backup to external storage, develop using darktable, then create smaller "web" versions) and that darktable bug/feature(?) introduced recently forced my parallel invocation to have `--max-procs 1` for a while. Was checking again to see if they fixed it and found this answer. Already using it while the bug is fixed, back to usual performance.

Comment: Thank you! The dedicated --configdir directory was the right trick.With my 12-thread CPU, exporting 36 images that take 84 s. single-threaded are done in 45 s. with 4 threads.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't run multiple instances of darktable at a time.

If your script is running 4 instances of `darktable-cli` in parallel, there's your error. You need to serialize your script to run at most one `darktable-cli` at a time. Having some kind of file locking mechanism that waits for the old `darktable-cli` to exit is needed. An example of such a program is `flock`.

For example, `flock /some/where/somefile.txt darktable-cli raw-file xmp-file jpg-file --width 1920 --height 1080 --core --conf plugins/imageio/format/jpeg/quality=50 --conf plugins/imageio/storage/disk/overwrite=true --library /tmp/darktable.db` ought to work.

Comment: Fortunately, you _can_ run multiple instances of darktable-cli at a time! Just need to use a dedicated --configdir directory for each instance, and them clean-up later. This allows me to run 4 instances of darktable-cli in parallel, get the most out of my 12-thread CPU and but export times to about half. Exporting 36 images that take 84 s. (single-threaded) are done in 53 s. with 2 threads, 45 s. with 4 threads, 53 s. with 6 threads ─ there's a balance to be found depending on your CPU and I/O bandwidth.